# What event does the probability ${{n\choose k}\over 6^n}$ describe?

Tags: probability, dice

The event "getting $k$ times the number $6$ in $n$ dice throws" has probability ${n\choose k}\cdot({1\over 6})^k\cdot({5\over6})^{n-k}$

So what event corresponds to ${{n\choose k}\over 6^n}$ ?

Comment: Well, first of all this doesn't sum up to $1$. This means that the event that would have these probability are not a partition of the event space $\Omega$

Comment: @P.Quinton What doesn't sum up to 1? The $\binom{n}{k}/6^n$ asked about in post is viewed in post as (it seems) probability of a single event.

Comment: It's the probability of getting the number $3$ $k$ times and the number $5$ the remaining $n-k$ times.

Comment: That's **one** of many events having that probability. The number of such events is $$\binom{6^n}{\binom nk}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just take two random number from $1$ to $6$, say $1$,$2$.

Throwing a dice $n$ times.

Then the probability to have $k$ $1$ appearing and all remaining are $2$ is $ \frac{{n}\choose{k}}{6^n}$.

Which is an extremely low probabilistic event, since the asymptotic estimate of ${n}\choose{k}$ is at most $2^n$.